# How to store JSONP into a Variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, charts

Im having problem with storing my JSONP data into variables. I need to store a number into a variable so that I can use it as an input for a Google Pie Chart. For example:

**My test.json**:

```
{
 "name": "ProjA",
 sp": 10,
 "current": 20
}
```

Now I want to get out the SP value.

I was trying with JQuery:

```
var sp = (function () {
    var sp = null;
    $.ajax({
        'async': false,
        'global': false,
        'url': test.json,
        'dataType': "json",
        'success': function (data) {
            json = data.sp;
        }
    });
    return json;
})();
```

Now I wanted to get the number 10 in a variable sp. And then put the sp, inside the google chart:

```
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
    data.addRows([
      ['Finished', sp,
      ['In Progress', 1],
      ['Canceled', 1],
      ['Rejected', 2]
    ]);
```

This is just a part code, the importmant thing is, it is not working. I thinki something is wrong with the storing of the variable.
Can someone please help me out?

**IMPORTMANT:** I do not have Web Server! This must be done with JSONP to avoid Cross-domain!

**EDIT:**

I have tried the below example:

```
 function getData(callback) {
$.ajax({
async: false,
global: false,
url: 'test.json', // make sure that you quote your filename
dataType: 'jsonp', // this is meant to be jsonp, not json
success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  callback(data.sp);
}


});
}
```

However there seems to be still problem with the Cross-domain, as the error in console states: *"XMLHttpRequest cannot load. Received an invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4"*

Still searching for a solution.

Comment: you forgot a double quote before the sp in your json data

Comment: You can't return data from a function that comprises an asynchronous call in the same way you can with a normal function. The `json` variable will be empty as you're discovering. You need to use a callback of some description.

Answer (score 0):

You're using an asynchronous call, so a normal return can't be used. There are a couple of ways you can do this:

**Callback**

```
function getData(callback) {
  $.ajax({
    async: false,
    global: false,
    url: 'test.json', // make sure that you quote your filename
    dataType: 'jsonp', // this is meant to be jsonp, not json
    success: function (data) {
      callback(data.sp);
    }
  });
}

getData(function (sp) {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
  data.addRows([
    ['Finished', sp], // close your braces
    ['In Progress', 1],
    ['Canceled', 1],
    ['Rejected', 2]
  ]);
});
```

**Promise**

```
function getData(callback) {
  return $.ajax({
    async: false,
    global: false,
    url: 'test.json',
    dataType: 'jsonp'
  });
}

getData.then(function (data) {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
  data.addRows([
    ['Finished', data.sp],
    ['In Progress', 1],
    ['Canceled', 1],
    ['Rejected', 2]
  ]);
});
```

This example utilises the fact that jQuery uses the [promise interface](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/).

Comment: I have tried your example, but it didnt work. Before the chart declaration, there's a function call I didnt write:  function drawChart{   .... and then comes var data = ... etc. 
Is that importmant?

Is jQueary 1.11-1 good, or do I need better version?
I am not sure what might be wrong. In the URL is enough to say: "test.json"  - my file is in the same folder.

Comment: @user3533253, if you can update the question or add the code to a JSfiddle i'll take a look, but I can't make any promises.

Comment: If you could be so nice and take a look at my Fiddle and try to help me out, Id be really gratefull: http://jsfiddle.net/86aBp/

Comment: @user3533253, take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/86aBp/1/. Does `drawChart` make more sense now?

Comment: It still doesnt show the chart. I tried that earlier also, like you did. Hm, I really cant figure out whats not working. JSONP should avoid cross-domain..

Comment: Are you actually getting any data back? Add a breakpoint/console.log(data) before `callback(data.sp);` to see what's being returned from your server.

Comment: I tried and it says it's an error:" Received an invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. "  
Here is a simplified fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/86aBp/2/

Comment: You need to check that your server is delivering the JSONP data like you want because it sounds like there's a problem there, and that's not something I can help you with. Sorry.

Comment: I have figured out. But I thought JSONP was implemented to avoid cross-domain, but my error suggests, that the cross domain is still causing problems!

Comment: Not sure if you will see this comment. But I ran into XAMPP, which lets me create a LOCAL WEB SERVER, which might be solution for our problem here?
So if I can create a local web server. How do I put the JSON file one that server - so that I can call it via URL ?